# Displaying only custom post types that's custom date fields values are either today or in the future

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using the following custom WordPress query to display data (events) from a custom post type on the homepage of my site:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'events',
                                           'posts_per_page' => '3',
                                           'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                                           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                                           'order' => 'ASC'
                       ));
```

This works as expected,however, as the nature of events is that they are always in the future i have a requirement that within the above query i need to filter out any post that's custom field 'event_date' is in the past, I also still wish to display, events occurring on the current day.

I've tried post_status => future but this only displays unpublished posts whereas all of my events are already published. Any insight is much appreciated Thank you

Comment: did you add filter post_where

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) custom field parameters.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => date( YOUR-FORMAT-HERE ),
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect, i had tried the meta_query but wasn't quite sure what to do with compare! thank you